# Why doesn't jQuery .show() or .hide() work with Opera 11.60 on localhost?

Tags: jquery, localhost

I'm currently running WAMP to do some coding. However,  jQuery .show() or .hide() does not seem to be working with Opera 11.60 on localhost but it works perfectly on the web server. Is anyone else experiencing this issue or know a way to work around this?

Comment: JavaScript is executed in the browser, so it does not matter *where* the code is located, it just has to be there. It seems that your code is not loaded properly when you run it at localhost.

Comment: That's strange, why does it work on the server? The code is identical.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. I had to clear my cache. Thanks!

Comment: don't cache ajax calls from jQuery to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get some problems with secure (js can run in same domain)
2. You have error before  "jQuery .show() or .hide()" and it not run yet
3. You use JQuery by external link and JQuery not loaded to client
4. Some think other, need more info